# "Impact" font not working on mobile Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, fonts

I've been struggling with the Impact font for about a year now.
It's supposed to be a web safe font, but it isn't.

When I use the standard "Impact" it will not work on mobile platforms. If I use a specific font @font-face, it's impossible to get same rendering on PC and Mac (I've tried about 20 different versions and spent about $200 on useless fonts).

I'm happy with the standard Impact as it works fine (with a few hacks). But it doesn't load on mobile phones (Chrome), and it's driving me crazy and makes me want to jump out the window. Seriously, I've had enough...

Comment: Please don't defenestrate yourself, it's not worth it over a font!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on this fiddle → https://jsfiddle.net/yakunins/8e56vdy7/

```
* {
  font-family: Impacto, Impact, sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Impacto;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAAXAQ...);
}
```

I got this result on my Android device:

[image: impact in Chrome Mobile]

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR: there's no such thing as a "web safe font"

The term originates from the pre mobile device era:
Sure, fonts like Impact are available on pretty much any Microsoft or Apple OS.
Most Linux distribution won't have them preinstalled either (albeit, you should be able to install them as [described here: Install Microsoft fonts on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxconfig.org/install-microsoft-fonts-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-desktop))

#### Workaround

1. Check if fonts are available via [`document.fonts.check()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check)
2. If not: load a replacement (in this example [Vernon Adams "Anton"](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anton?query=anton&category=Sans%20Serif)) using a asynchronous [FontFace.load()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/load) function
3. font installed? – skip font loading

```js
let fonts = [
{
    // Inter as replacement
    'font-family': 'Helvetica',
    'font-style': 'normal',
    'font-weight': 400,
    'src': 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v12/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7.woff2'
  },
  {
    // Load Anton  as replacement
    "font-family": "Impact",
    "font-style": "normal",
    "font-weight": 400,
    src: "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/anton/v23/1Ptgg87LROyAm3Kz-C8.woff2"
  }
];

let fontsToLoad = checkFontAvailability(fonts);
loadFonts(fontsToLoad)

function checkFontAvailability(fonts) {
  let info = [];
  let fontsToLoad = [];
  if (fonts.length) {
    fonts.forEach(function(font) {
      let fontFamily = font["font-family"];
      let fontApplied = document.fonts.check(`12px ${fontFamily}`);
      if (!fontApplied) {
        fontsToLoad.push(font);
      }
    });
    if (!fontsToLoad.length) {
      console.log('all fonts available!')
    }
  }
  return fontsToLoad;
}

async function loadFonts(fontsToLoad) {
  if (fontsToLoad.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fontsToLoad.length; i++) {
      let fontProps = fontsToLoad[i];
      let fontFamily = fontProps["font-family"];
      let fontWeight = fontProps["font-weight"];
      let fontStyle = fontProps["font-style"];
      let fontUrl = Array.isArray(fontProps["src"]) ?
        fontProps["src"][0][0] :
        fontProps["src"];
      if (fontUrl.indexOf("url(") === -1) {
        fontUrl = "url(" + fontUrl + ")";
      }
      let fontFormat = fontProps["src"][0][1] ? fontProps["src"][1] : "";
      const font = new FontFace(fontFamily, fontUrl);
      font.weight = fontWeight;
      font.style = fontStyle;
      await font.load();
      document.fonts.add(font);
      console.log(fontFamily, "loaded");

      // apply font styles to body
      let fontDOMEl = document.createElement("div");
      fontDOMEl.textContent = "";
      document.body.appendChild(fontDOMEl);
      fontDOMEl.setAttribute(
        "style",
        `position:fixed; height:0; width:0; overflow:hidden; font-family:${fontFamily}; font-weight:${fontWeight}; font-style:${fontStyle}`
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ImpactLookalike';
  font-style: 'normal';
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/anton/v23/1Ptgg87LROyAm3Kz-C8.woff2');
}

.impact {
  font-family: "Impact";
}

.anton {
  font-family: "ImpactLookalike";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="impact">Impact original</h1>
<h1 class="anton">Impact lookalike (Anton)</h1>
```

**Keep in mind: these fonts are not free!**
They are software products and therefore subjects of licensing.
By buying one of the aforementioned OS/products you'll obtain a desktop license - android devices usually do not include such a licence.

#### Better workaround

Stick to web fonts to ensure a consistent font display.